# Which EU countries were or still are China managed to have an influence on academic freedom?

Tags: european-union, china, freedom-of-speech

During a discussion, a colleague mentioned that China has an influence on academic freedom in many countries. This seems to be confirmed by [this article](https://chinaobservers.eu/the-eu-needs-to-face-chinas-threat-to-academic-freedom/) which mentions
academic exchanges as a mechanism for this:

> I argue that the positive model described above may not be a reality
> in case of China, which instead views academic exchange mainly as a
> tool to achieve its own economic and political goals on the global
> stage, spread its view on international norms and limit criticism
> towards it

Examples of academic freedom interference may refer to hiding articles related to sensitive (according to Chinese government) information about Tibet or 1989 Tiananmen Square protests and massacre.

I digged a little and managed to find the following countries that seem to have been affected by this:

- [UK (Cambridge)](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2017/aug/18/cambridge-university-press-blocks-readers-china-quarterly), but reverted [shortly after](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2017/08/21/cambridge-university-press-faces-backlash-after-bowing-to-china-censorship-pressure/)
- (possibly) Greece, Hungary, and Romania mentioned in [this article](https://carnegieendowment.org/2021/10/13/china-s-influence-in-southeastern-central-and-eastern-europe-vulnerabilities-and-resilience-in-four-countries-pub-85415):

> China’s presence has brought socioeconomic opportunities to Georgia,
> Greece, Hungary, and Romania. Yet it has exacerbated governance
> shortfalls, undermined elements of political and economic stability,
> and complicated the European Union’s ability to reach consensus on key
> issues.

I could not find information related to other EU countries. Are there any other EU countries that have at least one academic freedom "incident" related to China?

Comment: I believe that "have an influence" is an almost meaningless standard. China is a superpower and few countries (and few universities) will anger them thoughtlessly. If an university invites the Dalai Lama or an Uyghur, they will have considered and accepted Chinese anger, which means that China had an influence on the process. Even if the outcome is not the one China wanted.

Comment: Influence on the academic world is exercised through the control of peer reviewed journals and high level management of the universities.  Academic exchanges have no power to curtail academic freedom.

Comment: @FluidCode, ultimately funding is the key. Research grants, cooperation with industry, etc. Being in a confrontation with China might cut funding from some sources (which don't want to be dragged into it) and enhance funding from other sources (which want to make a point).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. In the case of the CUP, certain articles were blocked *inside China*, so academic freedom in the UK was unaffected. Are you looking for examples where the Chinese government influenced academic institutions headquartered in Europe, or where they impacted academic freedom within European countries?

Comment: @CharlieEvans I am interested in cases where they impacted academic freedom within EU countries.

Comment: @Alexei, how indirect can that "impact" be? Again a matter of degree. A corporate sponsor has business in China, some university researches human rights, the sponsor stops sponsoring? The academics could still publish, on their own dime.

Comment: "EU countries that have at least one academic freedom "incident"" This sounds like a very low bar. Depending on the size of the country, a single incident might account for only a negligible amount of academic research.

Comment: @o.m. I am thinking instead of a Chinese entity offering some sponsorship so that the university or a company removes an existing article or does not publish an article about a sensitive Chinese topic.

Comment: @o.m. *"ultimately funding is the key."* Even in this case Chinese impact would be negligible. If you are worried about academic freedom in Europe there are a lot bigger sources of worry.